# How can I skip deleted models during a loop doing expensive operations in Django?

Tags: django, python-3.x

I have a model called device. Each device has a `data_downloaded()` and `data_uploaded()` method, which look through the database for all records associated with that device, and sum up the data they've used. Each device can potentially have thousands of records that need to be aggregated to calculate its usage. My models look like this:

```
class Device(models.Model):
    ...
    mac_address = models.CharField(...)
    data_downloaded_cached = models.BigIntegerField(...)
    data_uploaded_cached = models.BigIntegerField(...)

    def data_downloaded(self):
        return DataRecord.objects.filter(mac_address=self.mac_address, direction="download").aggregate(data=Sum('data')).get("data", 0.00) or 0.00

    def data_uploaded(self):
        return DataRecord.objects.filter(mac_address=self.mac_address, direction="upload").aggregate(data=Sum('data')).get("data", 0.00) or 0.00

class DataRecord(models.Model):
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(...)
    mac_address = models.CharField(...)
    direction = models.CharField(...)
    data = models.BigIntegerField(...)
```

Since `device.data_downloaded()` and `device.data_uploaded()` are expensive operations that can take a minute to calculate (a lot of database rows need to be aggregated), I can't call those methods directly when a template is loading, so I cache the values. A background process runs the following code to update these cached values every few minutes:

```
for device in Device.objects.all():
    device.data_downloaded_cached = device.data_downloaded()
    device.data_uploaded_cached = device.data_uploaded()
    device.save()
```

When templates are displaying a list of devices, along with download and upload values for each devices, they can just use the cached values instead of trying to run these expensive operations on-the-fly, which would cause templates to take forever to load in a user's browser.

The problems I'm having are:

- If a device gets deleted while the code above is running, the device will still be processed by the for loop
- When the loop gets to the deleted device, calculates the values, and calls `device.save()`, the save operation will un-delete the deleted device (recreate it in the database)

I obviously don't care about updating cached values for devices that were recently deleted.
I also don't want to lock the database for minutes at a time while these expensive operations are taking place.
How can I make sure deleted devices are skipped?

Note: A device can be deleted before, or after the expensive operations begin. The main thing I care about is to make sure `device.save()` doesn't recreate the device. If I can make sure that expensive operations aren't performed on devices that have been deleted before these operations start, great. If not, I just need to make sure deleted devices aren't recreated by `device.save()`

Edit: On Willem Van Onsem's suggestion, I can do something like this:

```
totals = DataRecord.objects.values('mac_address').order_by('mac_address').annotate(downloaded=Sum('data', filter=Q(direction="download"))).annotate(uploaded=Sum('data', filter=Q(direction="upload")))

updates = []
for device in totals:
    dev = Device.objects.filter(mac_address=device['mac_address']).first()
    if dev:
        dev.data_downloaded_cached = device["downloaded"]
        dev.data_uploaded_cached = device["uploaded"]
        updates.append(dev)

Device.objects.bulk_update(updates, ['data_downloaded_cached', 'data_uploaded_cached'])
```

Does that sound right?

Comment: Instead of using `.aggregate(..)` per device, I think you need `.annotate(..)` here. That will do the summing in bulk and avoid the *N+1 problem*. Furthermore you probably should put a database index on the `direction`, or even better, use an `IntegerField` for that.

Comment: My direction is a `Boolean` field - the above is just a quick example. I'll try using `.annotate(..)` - thanks

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I tried your `.annotate(..)` suggestion. Not entirely sure if I did it right, but it seems to give me the right results. I added it above. I'm also not sure if there's a way to have the database save it immediately as it calculates each values without returning back to Python, or if that's a bad idea, as it might lock the database